# Auto adjusting image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple webpage where when you open it, the photo called "wallpaper.jpg" will adjust based on your window size so there's no scroll bars. The photo is `1920 x 1080` if it matters.

Currently I have:

```
<html>

<body bgcolor = "#000000">

<style>

img { 
height:100%;
width:100%; 
}

</style>

<img src = "wallpaper.jpg">

</body>

</html>
```

but it's still leaving a vertical scrollbar

Answer (score 3):

First things first:

- don't use `bgcolor` its deprecated,
- you should  reset `margin` on `body` because it has `margin:8px` by default (the value may change depending on the browser), to remove white space around.

Then using `img` you always going to have a vertical scrollbar if the `img` `height` is higher than viewport `height`(if `img` hasn't a parent with a `width`)

So a solution for that is using the image as a `background`, using [`cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) to make it full page responsive

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: url("//placehold.it/1920x1080") fixed no-repeat center center / cover
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by [@dippas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3448527/dippas) will work if you want to put the image in the background, but if you are using the `img` tag in the html document, heres a way!

```
html {
    height:100%;
}
body {
    position: relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding 0;
    margin: 0;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Here's my [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/kolemumojo/edit?html,css) implementation. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This method also works. Replace the "image.png" with a real link to your image.

```css
html { height: 100%; }
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<img src="image.png" height="100%" width="100%">
```